# ELMAH on IIS 7.5 producing HTTP 404 error

Tags: asp.net, elmah

So, have an ASP 3.5 site built using ELMAH.

It runs fine under IIS 5.1, I can see all the error pages, etc.

Set up the site on another machine running IIS 7.5.

Now when I go to my /admin/elmah.axd page, i see a 404 error from IIS 7.5.

Any thoughts on what I should look at?